# Why does my event binding not trigger any more after adding a "blocker" class in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, binding

I have a binding to a search input like this:

```
$(document).on('tablebeforefilter.results_filter',
   '#results_table:not(.bound)',
   function (e, data) {
     e.target.class += "bound";
     // stuff
   });
```

I'm using the `bound` class to prevent re-binding of the element if the page is reloaded (I'm using `Jquery Mobile` so this will happen when the user goes back and forth between two pages.

My problem is, doing it like this will correctly set the binding, but it will trigger my handler only once, presumable, because I add the 'bound' class to the element.

**Question**:
Why is it like this? I thought a binding set on `$(document) & some element` would be set and then runs no matter what class I add to this element. Only when the page is re-parsed my `bound` class prevents attaching the binding a second time. Why is my function no longer triggering if I add the blocking `bound` class?

Thanks!

Comment: if you're using jQuery... why not `$(this).addClass( 'bound' );` ?

Comment: mh. I like to use pure Javascript where I can. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Basically you are trying to prevent multiple event binding?

Comment: You are missing a space before `bound`. If the element already has class `foo`, you make it have class `foobound`. Not `foo` anymore, and not `bound`.

Comment: Isn't `.class` a string? So you add `"bound"` to the string `"results_filter"` and get `"results_filterbound"` – a completely new class.

Comment: yes. I know I can use `$(document).off('pagehide','.results_filter')` but the user will go back and forth between page A and B and I don't want to bind/unbind/bind...

Comment: Then why don't use standard ways of multiple binding prevention?

Comment: @Gajotres: so what is the standard way?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600 , search for chapter Prevent multiple event binding/triggering. Look at a solution 2 or 3. Solution 3 is an easiest one.

Answer (score 3):

`.class` is a string. So you add `"bound"` to the string `"results_filter"` and get `"results_filterbound"` – a completely new class. Therefore the `.on()` selector does no longer match. If you want to use `.class`, you have to add a blank, too:

```
e.target.class += " bound";
```

This adds a class `bound` and keeps the old class. To easily handle classes you could use `addClass()` or `removeClass()` of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery with ".on" is designed to be used with a changing html structure. So once you add the class "bound", your event is not triggered anymore.

Try using something like this instead

```
$(document).on('tablebeforefilter.results_filter', '#results_table', function (e, data) {
    var $table = $(this);
    if ($table.hasClass('bound') == false) {
        $table.addClass('bound');
    } else {
        // stuff with bound class
    }
    // common stuff for both cases
});
```